# How can I handle bottom sheet and bottom bar logic into viewmodel in kotlin compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet, scaffold, bottombar

I am making a scaffold and ModalBottomSheetLayout. ModalBottomSheetLayout contains scaffold and scaffold contains bottom bar and top bar but The codes are not very pleasing to the eye and I will have to copy them again during use on another screen. I couldn't do it myself because they are connected with each other, for example ModalBottomSheetLayout needs to use bottomSheetState and when a fab button is clicked, I close or open the bottomsheet, so I also need the bottomSheetState ui. So how can I write Scaffold bottom bar and top bar and BottomSheet logic in viewmodel?

Hear is my code:

**HomeScreen.kt**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel,
) {


    val image = sharedViewModel.userProfileImg

    val navBackStackEntry by navHostController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()


    val bottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
        initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden,
        confirmStateChange = {
            it != ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded
        })


    BackHandler(bottomSheetState.isVisible) {
        coroutineScope.launch { bottomSheetState.hide() }
    }

    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 12.dp, topEnd = 12.dp),
        sheetState = bottomSheetState,
        sheetContent = {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp)) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(12.dp),
                    text = "add",
                    fontSize = 16.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium
                )
                Divider()
                for (item in BottomSheetItemList().bottomSheetList.indices) {
                    BottomSheetRowItem(
                        text = BottomSheetItemList().bottomSheetList[item].title,
                        imgId = BottomSheetItemList().bottomSheetList[item].img
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    ){
        Scaffold(
            backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
            topBar = {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(horizontal = 4.dp)
                        .padding(vertical = 4.dp)
                ) {
                    Image(
                        painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(image),
                        contentDescription = "",
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .align(Alignment.CenterStart)
                            .padding(4.dp)
                            .width(40.dp)
                            .height(40.dp)
                            .clip(CircleShape)
                            .clickable {
                                navHostController.navigate(DashBoardScreen.AccountScreen.route)
                            })
                    Image(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(5.dp)
                            .align(Alignment.Center),
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_diyetkolik_logo),
                        contentDescription = "logo"
                    )
                }
            }, bottomBar = {
                Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                    BottomAppBar(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                        BottomNavigation {
                            BottomAppBarItems.values().toList().forEach { item ->
                                AddItem(
                                    screen = item,
                                    currentDestination = currentDestination,
                                    navController = navHostController
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    FancyCenterItem(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .align(Alignment.Center),
                        centerItemIcon = ImageVector.vectorResource(R.drawable.ic_bottom_bar_fab),
                        contentColor = DefaultDYTColor,
                        centerItemOnClick = {
                            coroutineScope.launch {
                                if (bottomSheetState.isVisible)
                                    bottomSheetState.hide()
                                else
                                    bottomSheetState.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded)
                            }
                        },
                        backgroundColor = Color.Transparent
                    )
                }
            }) { padding ->

            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(padding)
                    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            ) {
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp))
                HomeEditBtnAndText(text = "", buttonText = "Düzenle", onclickButton = {
                    navHostController.navigate(BottomBarScreen.PlansScreen.route)
                })
                HomeContentCard(
                    imageId = R.drawable.ic_dashboard_food,
                    content = "Yemek",
                    content2 = "0 Kcal, 2000 kalan",
                    buttonImgId = R.drawable.ic_dashboard_plus_math_sign
                )
                HomeContentCard(
                    imageId = R.drawable.ic_dashboar_water,
                    content = "Su",
                    content2 = "0 / 2lt",
                    buttonImgId = R.drawable.ic_dashboard_plus_math_sign
                )
                HomeContentCard(
                    imageId = R.drawable.ic_dashboard_step,
                    content = "",
                    content2 = "Apple healtden çek",
                    buttonImgId = R.drawable.ic_dashboard_plug_sign
                )
                HomeContentCard(
                    imageId = R.drawable.ic_dashboard_exercise,
                    content = "",
                    content2 = "0 Kcal",
                    buttonImgId = R.drawable.ic_dashboard_plus_math_sign
                )
                HomeContentCard(
                    imageId = R.drawable.ic_dashboard_weight,
                    content = "",
                    content2 = "54.5",
                    buttonImgId = R.drawable.ic_dashboard_plus_math_sign
                )
                HomeContentCard(
                    imageId = R.drawable.ic_dashboard_calorie,
                    content = "",
                    content2 = "",
                    buttonImgId = R.drawable.ic_dashboard_search
                )
               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FancyCenterItem is my fab button. When I click fab button bottomsheet open